# Youtube embed - pause video 1 when video 2 is played

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, embed

I am trying to find a way through the Youtube API to pause one video when another is playing, I have multiple Youtube Embeds on the same page. 
Is there a simple code for this that I am completely missing out on?

```
      <div id="video_youtube" style="min-height:600px; margin-top:1%;">
        <iframe id='player1' style="margin-right:2%; padding-bottom:1%;" width="500px" height="281px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/rZye11nxOOQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
          </iframe>
        <iframe id='player2' style="padding-bottom:1%;" width="500px" height="281px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8Q89hEnkYH4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
          </iframe>
     </div>
```

I found one that shows a code that allows you to do the same with two videos, 
but I think if I had to add more videos this code is too manual and will get longer and complex.

```
 <div id="player1"></div>
 <div id="player2"></div>
 <script>
   var tag = document.createElement('script');
   tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
   var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
        height: '293',
        width: '520',
        videoId: 'zXV8GMSc5Vg',
        events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
    player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
        height: '293',
        width: '520',
        videoId: 'LTy0TzA_4DQ',
        events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        stopVideo(event.target.a.id);
    }
}

function stopVideo(player_id) {
    if (player_id == "player1") {
        player2.stopVideo();
    } else if (player_id == "player2") {
        player1.stopVideo();
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you created an object that held all your player objects, and made sure that the name of the property referencing each player matched that player's ID? Then your stop method could just do a simple javascript for ... in ... loop (which loops through the property names rather than the values):

```
 <div id="player1"></div>
 <div id="player2"></div>
 <!-- add as many as you need -->
 <script>
   var tag = document.createElement('script');
   tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
   var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player={};
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player.player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
        height: '293',
        width: '520',
        videoId: 'zXV8GMSc5Vg',
        events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
    player.player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
        height: '293',
        width: '520',
        videoId: 'LTy0TzA_4DQ',
        events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
    // add more here, ensuring that in player.[whatever] the 'whatever' is the same as the ID. You could very easily script this process as well so you don't repeat yourself.
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        stopVideos(event.target.a.id);
    }
}

function stopVideos(player_id) {
    for (p in player) {
        if (p!==player_id) {
          player[p].stopVideo(); // all videos will stop playing except the one that triggered the event
        }
    }
}
</script>
```